# Why is the King of Nineveh in Yonah unnamed?

Tags: names, malchut-royalty, yonah-jonah-book-of

To clarify, I'm not asking who the King of Nineveh in Sefer Yonah was. I'm simply wondering why he's unnamed (see [Yonah 3:6-7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jonah.3.6-7?lang=bi)). He was probably some sort of Assyrian ruler, and several of those were named in Tanach. Why is the one in Yonah unnamed?

Comment: Because it doesn't matter? Similarly, why wasn't the ship captain named?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it does matter. This isn't just any "goyishe" city, this the capital of the empire that ruled the Kingdom of Israel at the time. Does that not bear some significance in understanding why Yonah was so against going there? בדיעבד, perhaps a better question would have been why the importance of Ninenveh seems to be downplayed in the book - presented as a city-state in the middle of nowhere (Yonah can't find shade outside of the city...) ruled by a nameless king?

Comment: There are some sources (e.g. Targum) who say that the King was פַּרְעֹה. The name of פַּרְעֹה is also not mentioned in the Torah.  Why mention the name of this king? Whether it was פַּרְעֹה  or not?

Comment: There are some reasonable answers already, but I'm wondering if part of the reason is that Yonah seems to me to be written as a parable, more than any other book of Tanach that I can think of (except Iyov, which Chazal themselves say may not have ever happened). I'm not arguing on the historicity of the events, for example Yonah ben Amitai was an actual prophet mentioned elsewhere, but the Gr'a writes a peirush on it as a parable for the life of a human being. (Of course, he kinda did that for the Megillah as well.)

Comment: If he would of been commanded to go to the king and say the prophecy, I would understand why the name would be relevant. However, he gave his prophecy directly to the people. The king only heard about it second hand. He was entirely irrelevant to the story. He did make an edict to fast etc but chazal tell us that the real thing was the Teshuva not the fasting, so he was really mostly irrelevant to the story. His name is therefore not mentioned

Comment: In the context of the story the fact that he was king was and did Teshuva and instructed  the people how to do so important. Historical information like his name was not and would have detracted from the main message of the story.

Comment: @Schmerel "would have detracted from the main message of the story". I'm wondering if we would say that about (for instance) Pichol the general of Avimelech's army, who came with him to meet Avraham. Does it detract, or is it just a detail that may or may not be present and I don't know why?

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Is there a study somewhere of why some people in Tanach are named and others not?  If "it doesn't matter", one must explain why in cases the person is named it *does* matter.

Answer (score 1):

Every single letter in Torah teaches us something. There was nothing to be gained by noting the name of anyone left unnamed, and if there was something to be gained but not in the way of the possuk, the midrash might.